# Why does joint links pile up to origin after running the control launch file?

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-melodic

This is the spherical bot which I am working on from the last question. everything seems to run properly while launching the gazebo and rviz launch files. but the moment I launch the control launch file, the joints and links pile up at the origin. What could be the reason?

Also I am not able to control the joint after launching that control launch file

PLEASE LET ME KNOW IF THERE IS ANY MISTAKE FROM MY SIDE OR IF YOU NEED MORE INFORMATION.

Thanks for your time :)

Here's the gazebo with plugin file

````
<robot
  name="spb">
  <link
    name="base_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-0.00028921 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.38748" />
      <!-- <inertia
        ixx="2.1656E-05"
        ixy="0"
        ixz="0"
        iyy="4.4343E-05"
        iyz="-0"
        izz="2.4037E-05" /> -->
        <inertia
        ixx="3.94176E-05"
        ixy="0"
        ixz="0"
        iyy="3.94176E-05"
        iyz="-0"
        izz="8.09748E-05" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://spb/meshes/base_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.79216 0.81961 0.93333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://spb/meshes/base_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <link
    name="hull_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 -0.03481"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.15035" />
      <!-- <inertia
        ixx="3.1656E-05"
        ixy="0"
        ixz="0"
        iyy="5.0531E-05"
        iyz="0"
        izz="3.188E-05" /> -->
        <inertia
        ixx="2.506E-02"
        ixy="0"
        ixz="0"
        iyy="2.506E-02"
        iyz="0"
        izz="2.506E-02" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 -0.03481"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://spb/meshes/hull_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="brick_red_mf">
        <color
          rgba="0.7 0.0 0.1 1.0" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 -0.03481"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://spb/meshes/hull_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="joint1"
    type="continuous">
    <origin
      xyz="0.03481 0.0 0"
      rpy="-1.5708 0.011859 -1.5708" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="hull_link" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 1" />
  </joint>
  <!--                GAZEBO RELATED PART                             -->
  <!-- ROS Control plugin for Gazebo -->
  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
      <robotNamespace>/spb</robotNamespace>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>

  <!-- transmission -->
  <transmission name="transmis1">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <actuator name="motor1">
      <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
    <joint name="joint1">
      <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
  </transmission>



</robot>```


HERE'S THE RVIZ LAUNCH FILE  

``` <launch>
  <arg
    name="model" />
  <param
    name="robot_description"
    textfile="$(find spb)/urdf/spb.urdf" />
  <node
    name="joint_state_publisher_gui"
    pkg="joint_state_publisher_gui"
    type="joint_state_publisher_gui" />
  <node
    name="robot_state_publisher"
    pkg="robot_state_publisher"
    type="robot_state_publisher" />
  <node
    name="rviz"
    pkg="rviz"
    type="rviz"
    args="-d $(find spb)/urdf.rviz" />
</launch> ```

HERE'S CONTROL LAUNCH FILE  

``` <launch>

  <!-- Load joint controller configurations from YAML file to parameter server -->
  <rosparam file="$(find spb_control)/config/spb_control.yaml" command="load"/>

  <!-- load the controllers -->
  <node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false"
    output="screen" ns="/spb" args="joint_state_controller
                      joint1_position_controller"/>
                      <!-- joint2_position_controller"/> -->

  <!-- convert joint states to TF transforms for rviz, etc -->
  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher"
    respawn="false" output="screen">
    <remap from="/joint_states" to="/spb/joint_states" />
  </node>

</launch>

HERE'S THE CONFIGURATION FILE OF THE CONTROLLER 

```spb:
  # Publish all joint states -----------------------------------
  joint_state_controller:
    type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
    publish_rate: 50  
  
  # Position Controllers ---------------------------------------
  joint1_position_controller:
    type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
    joint: joint1
    pid: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0}
  # joint2_position_controller:
  #   type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
  #   joint: joint2
  #   pid: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0}
````

[image]

Comment: Does your "empty world" have a ground plane? What is the full text of the inertia warning we see in the screenshot?

Comment: [ WARN] [1684223115.196854571]: The root link base_link has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL does not support a root link with an inertia.  As a workaround, you can add an extra dummy link to your URDF.

I guess this is irrelevant and could be ignored as I used to get this warning earlier when I worked with my previous robots, the simulation used to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

It's really difficult to diagnose the issue without the full URDF/SDF of your world, but my guess is that the joint controller is somehow putting the world in an invalid state by applying large joint forces. I would first disable/remove the controller and see if you still have the issue. If the issue goes away, you probably have a link with invalid or unrealistic inertial properties. You can visualize inertia properties for each link to help with debugging this.

Comment: I have added the URDF of the robot and about the world, it's just an empty world. The problem seem to go away when the controller is not launched. I have entered the inertial properties manually as well, but could you please tell me how to visualize inertia properties?

Comment: Is there a reason you're running the `joint_state_publisher_gui`? I don't think it's needed and may interfere with your joint controller.

To visualize the inertia, go to the Gazebo menu and select View->Inertia.

Also make sure that your object is not in collision with the ground when simulation starts.

Comment: I will check for the joint state publisher thing, thanks for the information.